# Ajax PHP file upload mistake

Tags: php, ajax, multipartform-data

I have this code in client side:

```
fileUpload: function monkey(){
        var file = t.gI("photoFile"); //get element by photoFile
        var formData = new FormData();
        console.log(file.files.length);
        formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
        var req = t.gR(); //XMLHTTPRequest
        req.open('POST', 'php/fileupload.php', true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data", true);
        req.send(formData);
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState === 4) {
                if (req.status == 200 && req.status < 300) {
                    t.gI("eventBox").innerHTML = req.responseText; //eventbox error handler
                    adminHandler.eventBox();
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And this in server side:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type:multipart/form-data');

    echo $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
?>
```

And I got this error msg:

[15-Jun-2015 12:03:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
[15-Jun-2015 12:03:21 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: upload in /home/webprogb/public_html/php/fileupload.php on line 4

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: you don't output multipart/form-data from the server. that's for a client sending a normal non-file-upload form **TO** the server. your server-side script should be just `<?php echo 'foo' ?>`. no need for a header if all you're doing is dumping out a filename. and the undefined index means that no file was uploaded. `var_dump($_FILES)` will probably show it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for file uploading with ajax in pure javascript. Change this "#fileUploader" according to file field ID.

```
var AjaxFileUploader = function () {
    this._file = null;
    var self = this;

    this.uploadFile = function (uploadUrl, file) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
           //error
        };

        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            //error
        };

        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            //error
        };

        xhr.open("post", uploadUrl, true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

        xhr.send(file);
    };
};

AjaxFileUploader.IsAsyncFileUploadSupported = function () {
    return typeof (new XMLHttpRequest().upload) !== 'undefined';
}

 if (AjaxFileUploader.IsAsyncFileUploadSupported) {
        ajaxFileUploader = new AjaxFileUploader();

        $("form").submit(function () {
            var uploader = $("#fileUploader")[0];

            if (uploader.files.length == 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                ajaxFileUploader.uploadFile(
                    "/YourUploadUrl",
                    uploader.files[0]);
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can I do it without jquery?

Comment: @PumpkinSeed i have updated the answer :) please check

Comment: Not worked for me I am trying to upload to remote host with credentials so I also have set the origin on server end. I am getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/test. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access.` But when I used `$.ajax` it worked